# Python Pandas, select and drop rows grouped by multiple columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Suppose I have a pandas DataFrame with the following columns and data:

```
    user            time           session         time_diff
0   21.0    2022-12-16 14:03:08        5           NaN
1   21.0    2022-12-16 14:03:10        5           2.0
2   21.0    2022-12-16 14:03:12        6           2.0
3   21.0    2022-12-16 14:03:13        6           1.0
4   21.0    2022-12-28 14:49:54        16          1039601.0
5   30.0    2022-12-16 14:03:16        5           1039598.0
6   30.0    2022-12-16 14:03:18        5           2.0
7   30.0    2022-12-16 14:03:20        6           2.0
```

I would like to select those rows where for the same user and session the time difference (time_diff column in seconds) is less than some threshold (10 seconds, for example). Which would result in the following output:

```
    user            time           session         time_diff
1   21.0    2022-12-16 14:03:10        5           2.0
3   21.0    2022-12-16 14:03:13        6           1.0
6   30.0    2022-12-16 14:03:18        5           2.0
```

I could probably iterate through each row and select records where id = id of the preceding row and session = session of the preceding row but I believe this is not the most optimal approach.

```
df.groupby(['user', 'session']).filter(lambda x: (x.time_diff <= 10).any())
```

also does not produce the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

- Group by `["user", "session"]` ([`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)) and check [`.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) for column `"time"`.
- For the resulting `Series` check < 10 seconds using [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html).
- Finally, use the resulting `Series` (populated with `True` & `False`) for [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to retrieve the desired subset.

```py
out = df[df.groupby(["user", "session"])['time'].diff()
         .lt(pd.Timedelta('00:00:10'))]
out

   user                time  session  time_diff
1  21.0 2022-12-16 14:03:10        5        2.0
3  21.0 2022-12-16 14:03:13        6        1.0
6  30.0 2022-12-16 14:03:18        5        2.0
```

---

**Option 2**

(*Assuming your data is properly sorted on `user` and `session`*.)

- Apply [`Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) to column `"time"` and check < 10 seconds.
- Now, also check whether row values for `user` and `session` are both equal to ([`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)) the values in the previous row ([`df.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)). Use [`df.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) row-wise to get `False` for all shifts to a new group.
- Finally, apply boolean indexing to select from the `df` where both conditions are `True` (using the bitwise operator `&`).

```py
out2 = df[df.time.diff().lt(pd.Timedelta('00:00:10')) & 
          df[['user','session']].eq(df[['user','session']].shift(1)).all(axis=1)]

out2.equals(out)
# True
```

---

**Performance comparison**

Option 1 will be fastest. Both will be faster than the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77240393/18470692) offered by [@AndrejKesely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely).

```py
# opt1: 1.75 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# opt2: 3.1 ms ± 133 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# AK:   7.02 ms ± 300 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

**Data used**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'user': {0: 21.0, 1: 21.0, 2: 21.0, 3: 21.0, 4: 21.0, 5: 30.0, 6: 30.0, 
                 7: 30.0}, 
        'time': {0: '2022-12-16 14:03:08', 1: '2022-12-16 14:03:10', 
                 2: '2022-12-16 14:03:12', 3: '2022-12-16 14:03:13', 
                 4: '2022-12-28 14:49:54', 5: '2022-12-16 14:03:16', 
                 6: '2022-12-16 14:03:18', 7: '2022-12-16 14:03:20'}, 
        'session': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 16, 5: 5, 6: 5, 7: 6}, 
        'time_diff': {0: np.nan, 1: 2.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1039601.0, 5: 2, 
                      6: 2.0, 7: 2.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```